Unexpected Type Inference for keyof Combined with Omit in Generic Type
TypeScript Version: 5.5.4
Code:
type Trans<T> = Omit<T, never>; // A generic type that should return T without modification.

interface T1 {
    a: string;
}

interface T2 {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

type X1 = Trans<keyof T2>; // Expected: 'a' | 'b'; 
type X2 = T1 & T2;
type X3 = Trans<T1 & T2>; // As expected: T1 & T2.

Issue:
Unexpected:
type X1 = {
    readonly [x: number]: string;
    [Symbol.iterator]: () => StringIterator<string>;
    toString: () => string;
    charAt: (pos: number) => string;
    charCodeAt: (index: number) => number;
    concat: (...strings: string[]) => string;
    ... 43 more ...;
    at: (index: number) => string | undefined;
}

My Question:
Why does X1 become this complex string type instead of the expected 'a' | 'b'?
This behavior appears when combining keyof with Omit in a generic context, and I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind this type inference. Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated.
Search Terms:

keyof
Omit
generic type inference
TypeScript

I'm not reporting this as a bug but rather seeking clarification on the behavior I'm observing.
In the above code:

Trans<T> is a generic type that doesn't modify T, as it simply omits never.
I expect X1 to be 'a' | 'b', as keyof T2 should infer the keys of T2.

However, X1 is inferred as a complex string-related type, including methods like charAt, concat, etc., which seems unexpected.

Omit<T, never> can only be an identity if T is an object type.  If you are passing in a subtype of string as T, then you are going to be evaluating Pick<T, keyof T> and keyof T is going to be a big union of all the keys of string, and then you're explicitly asking for that big horrible object type. The only times mapped types over primitives are identities is if the mapped type is homomorphic, and that's not happening with Omit. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53169.

(see prev comment) Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

The problem is that Omit is meant to work with objects, not unions. keyof returns a union of string literals, so Omit will not work correctly with that. What you need is Exclude. You can take a look to the docs here.
type Trans<T> = Exclude<T, never>

interface T1 {
    a: string;
}

interface T2 {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

type X1 = Trans<keyof T2>; // As expected: 'a' | 'b'; 
type X2 = T1 & T2;
type X3 = Trans<T1 & T2>; // As expected: T1 & T2.


